# How to stop autoscroll bottom when scroll top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem because I do not understand how I can stop the auto-scroll vertically to bottom. In practice, I would like to lock it while click the scroll bar above to start it and when I'm completely bottom. This is the code jQuery:

```
$(function() {
        startRefresh();
    });

    function startRefresh() {
        start = setTimeout(startRefresh, 1000);
        $.post('data.php', function(data) {
            $('.view').html(data);
        });
        scroll();
    }

function scroll() {
   $('.view').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.view')[0].scrollHeight
   }, 1500);
}
scroll();
```

HTML

```
<div class="view"></div>
```

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the question. But I think OP is asking how to do this scroll thing on click of something

Comment: What is not clear in the question? @Huangism

Comment: `In practice, I would like to lock it while click the scroll bar above to start it and when I'm completely bottom.` I don't understand that sentence

Comment: in simple terms: Start the scroll from bottom to the top by removing the auto scroll

Comment: This autoscroll, it will run when the page loads and stop after it run its course. So what's the issue? Create a fiddle if you can

Comment: this is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/FEqXm/

Comment: The fiddle does not do anything. I added this http://jsfiddle.net/FEqXm/1/ is this what you want?

Comment: @Huangism no...is a bit complicated to explain :P ... I want how does the facebook chat ... for example: messages start at the bottom

Comment: If you want the scroll to start at bottom then change the 1500 to 0 so it goes there right away. If more content is added then you have to call scroll again to make it go to the bottom

Comment: yes, but if i want to go top, the scroll go bottom automatically

Comment: If you don't want the scroll to bottom then don't call the function http://jsfiddle.net/FEqXm/2/ is an example where you can add content and it scrolls to bottom every time, like a chat

Comment: mmm, but isn't possible with a clearTimeout() to lock the update when go to the top and start update when go to the bottom ?

Comment: You lost me there. As far as your code goes, the startFresh function runs only once and that's when the doc is ready.